# Sandbox copies and deployment

Tags: sandbox

I'll try to explain this so it makes sense.

We contracted a developer for some customization. She created a full sandbox from our Enterprise production environment. Our Opportunity object was limited to 500 custom fields which we are quickly using and need more to finish the development, so we upgraded to Unlimited Edition.

Unfortunately, we didn't realize the sandbox wouldn't have the additional field limits because it's a copy of our original Enterprise edition. We do not want to deploy the new version yet.

An alternative we are thinking of is to create another copy of our new unlimited production environment that now has limits of 800 custom fields per object. Then deploying the developing sandbox, which will then adopt the Unlimited field limitations, then making another sandbox from that, so we can continue our development, then redeploy the copy of the Unlimited Edition of our Production environment.

If we do it after hours we are hoping no one will be the wiser. Here's my concern. Someone else told me that once we deploy the new version with customization into production and then redeploy the Unlimited production copy we made, the new customization will still be present in our production environment. Basically a mix of the old and new. Is this true? We want the additional fields in our developing sandbox, but we don't want any of the development we've done so far to be present in the production environment yet, as it is quite different and has a lot of automation from what everyone is used to and will require re-training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is, yes that is true.

i think your question is : If you deploy from new or old sandbox then will it overwrite other component in production?

The simple answer is: No, it wont overwrite other component.

When you deploy specific(object/field etc.) component then only that component is updated on target environment and all other component works as it is.

Comment: Thanks AtulRajGuru9. I guess we'll have to do what we can for now, deploy what we have when ready, then create another sandbox to finish development and deploy part 2 of the new edition. I guess we'll be keeping the contracted developer around a bit longer than we budgeted for.